Strapi api not returning fields
I have a TrustedByBanner component in the published collection type:

In graphql playground I am able to fetch the component with the data:


But inside my app when I fetch the page using same query it does not return the content of that component. When I try to fetch the component inside my app it does not return any of those fields. When logging the component i get only:
{ __typename: 'ComponentSharedTrustedByBanner' }

But no title, no subtitle or orgs. Is there any extra setting for fields? I made sure the fields are not private, but it doesn't show them when I use exactly the same query in my code like the on on the playground.

You should share the code you're trying to use to retrieve the information so that someone can help diagnose what's wrong

should also add a graphql tag
